# How to fix proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

In [How to consume a REST API in Go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYk8XAKxhxU)  a [fully working example code](https://github.com/NerdCademyDev/golang/blob/main/12_json_to_struct/main.go) is provided to call a public REST API. But if I try the sample this error occurs:

```
error getting cat fact: 
      Get "https://catfact.ninja/fact": 
      proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

The [documentation about http](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.21.1#hdr-Clients_and_Transports) states

> For control over proxies, TLS configuration, keep-alives, compression, and other settings, create a Transport:

and from the [Transport documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.21.1#Transport):

```golang
    // DialContext specifies the dial function for creating unencrypted TCP connections.
    // If DialContext is nil (and the deprecated Dial below is also nil),
    // then the transport dials using package net.
    //
    // DialContext runs concurrently with calls to RoundTrip.
    // A RoundTrip call that initiates a dial may end up using
    // a connection dialed previously when the earlier connection
    // becomes idle before the later DialContext completes.
    DialContext func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)
```

So I assume that I have to configure Dialcontext to enable an insecure connection `without TLS`  from my client to the proxy. But I do not know how to do this. Reading these:

- [How to do proxy and TLS in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401128/how-to-do-proxy-and-tls-in-golang);
- [How to HTTP/HTTPS GET via Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438278/how-to-http-https-get-via-proxy); and
- [How to do a https request with bad certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122159/how-to-do-a-https-request-with-bad-certificate/59738724#59738724)

did not help either. Some have the same error `proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake` and explain the cause:

> This is because the proxy answers with an plain HTTP error to the strange HTTP request (which is actually the start of the TLS handshake).

But [Steffen's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61402583/819887) has no sample code how to set up `DialContext func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string)` and both [Bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59738724/819887) and [cyberdelia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122718/819887) suggest to set `tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}` for example like this

```golang
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

But the above has not effect. I still get the same error. And the connection is still calling `https://*` instead of `http://*`

This is the sample code and my attempt to include the above recommendations and adapt it:

```golang
var tr = &http.Transport{ TLSClientConfig: 
                           &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}, } 
                           // lacks DialContext config
var client*  http.Client = &http.Client{Transport: tr} // modified * added
// var client *http.Client // code from tutorial

type CatFact struct {
    Fact   string `json:"fact"`
    Length int    `json:"length"`
}

func GetCatFact() {
    url := "http://catfact.ninja/fact" // changed from https to http
    var catFact CatFact

    err := GetJson(url, &catFact)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error getting cat fact: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("A super interesting Cat Fact: %s\n", catFact.Fact)
    }
}

func main() {
    client = &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
    GetCatFact()
    // same error 
    // proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does 
    //                   not look like a TLS handshake
    // still uses https 
    // for GET catfact.ninja
}
```

How can the connection be configured to use unencrypted connection from myClient over the proxy to the server? Will setting the `DialContext func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string)` help to do this? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type CatFact struct {
    Fact   string `json:"fact"`
    Length int    `json:"length"`
}

// Custom dialing function to handle connections
func customDialContext(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
    return conn, err
}

// Function to get a cat fact
func GetCatFact(client *http.Client) {
    url := "https://catfact.ninja/fact"  // Reverted back to https
    var catFact CatFact

    err := GetJson(url, &catFact, client)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error getting cat fact: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("A super interesting Cat Fact: %s\n", catFact.Fact)
    }
}

// Function to send a GET request and decode the JSON response
func GetJson(url string, target interface{}, client *http.Client) error {
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error sending GET request: %w", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return fmt.Errorf("received non-OK HTTP status: %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(target)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error decoding JSON response: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    // Create a custom Transport with the desired settings
    tr := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,  // Use the proxy settings from the environment
        DialContext: customDialContext,    // Use the custom dialing function
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,  // Skip certificate verification (not recommended in production)
        },
    }

    // Create a new HTTP client using the custom Transport
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
        Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
    }

    // Call the function to get a cat fact
    GetCatFact(client)
}
```

It includes:

- **A custom dialing function `customDialContext`:**
  That function is currently a simple wrapper around `net.Dial`, but it provides a place where custom dialing logic could be introduced if necessary. It serves as a custom dialing function that is used to create network connections.
- **Transport configuration:**

  - The revised code configures a custom `http.Transport` with specific settings, including a custom dialing function, proxy settings from the environment, and a TLS configuration that skips certificate verification (for testing).
  - The original code also attempted to configure a custom `http.Transport`, but it only included a TLS configuration to skip certificate verification, and did not set a custom dialing function or proxy settings.
- **Client configuration:**

  - The revised code creates a new `http.Client` using the custom `http.Transport`, and sets a timeout of 10 seconds.
  - The original code also attempted to create a new `http.Client` with a custom `http.Transport`, but later in the `main` function, it overwrote the `client` variable with a new `http.Client` with a default `Transport` and a timeout of 10 seconds, effectively discarding the custom `Transport`.
- **Function signatures:**

  - The revised code modifies the `GetCatFact` and `GetJson` functions to accept an `*http.Client` parameter, allowing them to use the custom `http.Client` created in `main`.
  - The original code did not pass the `http.Client` to these functions, so they would have used the default `http.Client` provided by the `net/http` package.
- **URL:**

  - The revised code reverts the URL back to "https://catfact.ninja/fact" in the `GetCatFact` function, as the server redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS anyway.
  - The original code had changed the URL to "http://catfact.ninja/fact" in an attempt to avoid the TLS handshake error.

---

> Beeing new to Go, I would expect that some "special" values must be passed to the signature `func customDialContext(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)` to change the TLS handshake to "non-tls" or to ignore errors.
>
> But I can not see anything like setting TLS version or something similar. What and where is the magic that makes Go to ignore the handshake error?

The `customDialContext` function in the code provided above does not contain any logic to specifically ignore TLS handshake errors or to change a TLS handshake to a non-TLS connection. It only provides a custom dialing function, which, in the provided form, just directly calls `net.Dial` without any special handling.

The mechanism to ignore TLS certificate verification errors is actually provided by the `TLSClientConfig` field of the `http.Transport` struct, specifically by setting the `InsecureSkipVerify` field to `true`:

```golang
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

That configuration tells Go to skip verifying the server's certificate chain and host name, which is a part of the TLS handshake process. However, it does not ignore other types of TLS handshake errors or switch to a non-TLS connection. It is generally not advisable to use `InsecureSkipVerify: true` in production environments, as it disables important security checks.

If you want to force a non-TLS (plain HTTP) connection, you would generally just use an `http://` URL instead of an `https://` URL. However, if the server or proxy server redirects HTTP to HTTPS (as is the case with `http://catfact.ninja/fact`), then the client will follow the redirect and switch to a TLS connection.

Comment: Perfect; this worked out of the box.  Beeing new to Go i would expect that some "special" values must be passed to the signature `func customDialContext(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)` to change the TLS handshake to "non-tls" or to ignore errors. But i can not see anything like [setting TLS version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?view=net-7.0) or something similar. What and where is the magic that makes Go to ignore the handshake error?

Comment: @surfmuggle I have edited the answer to address your first comment.