# go install fails due to proxy and tls handshake

Tags: go, installation, proxy, http-proxy, handshake

The command

```bash
go install -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest
```

fails with the message

> proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

I assume that the cause is that i am behind a corporate proxy that does not use https for the communication from my client (my windows box) to the proxy server.

The windows user environment variables `C:\>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` for `proxy` and `no_proxy` are set like this

```bash
C:\>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment | findstr /R .PROXY.

HTTP_PROXY=http://myuser:mypass@proxy.company:port
HTTPS_PROXY=https://myuser:mypass@proxy.company:port
# i also tried http 
# HTTPS_PROXY=http://myuser   <-- no https
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,.mycomp.com,.foo.mycomp,localhost:5001
```

changing the value of `HTTPS_PROXY`  from `https://myuser...` to `http://myuser...` made no difference. The git config `git config -l` for http has these settings

```bash
C:\>git config -l  | findstr /R http.

http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.proxy=http://myuser:mypass@proxy.company:port
http.sslverify=false
https.proxy=http://myuser:mypass@proxy.company:port
```

#### Update

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77217851/819887) a `customDialContext` is used to avoid the same error message `proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake` but for a different task (calling a rest service).

```golang
// Custom dialing function to handle connections
func customDialContext(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
    return conn, err
}
```

### Question

What do i have to do

- so that i can use `go install`
- and avoid or ignore the error `proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake`
- Can a custom dial function be used for the install command (see Update above)?

Answer (score 1):

In a corporate environment, I would recommend [`genotrance/px`](https://github.com/genotrance/px)

- you can launch it with a [`--pac=file` option](http://genotrance/px) or a [`.ini pac` directive](https://github.com/genotrance/px/blob/7e1cfd2dc2a2c925f0cf6c70388a8b4da7699ff5/px.ini#L10-L13).
- it runs on 127.0.0.1:3128 by default

That means your `HTTPS_PROXY` becomes `http://127.0.0.1:3128` (no more `myuser:mypass`!)

Your settings:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Note: `HTTPS_PROXY` reference the same proxy through HTTP, *not* HTTPS.

And in your [`px.ini`](https://github.com/genotrance/px/blob/master/px.ini), only put your `server = http://my.corporate.proxy` (again, HTTP only).
Launch it once (per Windows session), and then try your internet connections from CLI or your Go programs.

Comment: From px the readme `If SSPI is not available or not preferred, providing a username in domain\username format allows Px to authenticate as that user. ` this sounds promising. Currently the setup on my msft box is this: `under proxy settings a script like http://127.0.0.x:xxx/localproxy-xxx.pac is loaded. This file contains different proxy ips with different purposes. Running tracert  127.0.0.x results in 1 hop and contains kubernetes.docker.internal` I wonder if px and the current setup will go along with each other. I will try to set [Px](https://github.com/genotrance/px/) up to find out.

Comment: @surfmuggle You can reference your pac file in the `pac =` section of the [`px.ini`](https://github.com/genotrance/px/blob/0064b74ec398b7a5adaa39e0ba671216b9dd2491/px.ini#L8-L11).